# Looking for a replace-in-string function in elisp

Tags: regex, string, replace, emacs

I'm looking for an equivalent of `replace-regexp-in-string` that just uses literal strings, no regular expressions.

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "." "bar" "foo.buzz") => "barbarbarbarbarbarbarbar"
```

But I want

```
(replace-in-string "." "bar" "foo.buzz") => "foobarbuzz"
```

I tried various `replace-*` functions but can't figure it out.

**Edit**

In return for the elaborate answers I decided to benchmark them (yea, I know all benchmarks are wrong, but it's still interesting).

The output of `benchmark-run` is `(time, # garbage collections, GC time)`:

```
(benchmark-run 10000
  (replace-regexp-in-string "." "bar" "foo.buzz"))

  => (0.5530160000000001 7 0.4121459999999999)

(benchmark-run 10000
  (haxe-replace-string "." "bar" "foo.buzz"))

  => (5.301392 68 3.851943000000009)

(benchmark-run 10000
  (replace-string-in-string "." "bar" "foo.buzz"))

  => (1.429293 5 0.29774799999999857)
```

replace-regexp-in-string with a quoted regexp wins. Temporary buffers do remarkably well.

**Edit 2**

Now with compilation! Had to do 10x more iteration:

```
(benchmark-run 100000
  (haxe-replace-string "." "bar" "foo.buzz"))

  => (0.8736970000000001 14 0.47306700000000035)

(benchmark-run 100000
  (replace-in-string "." "bar" "foo.buzz"))

  => (1.25983 29 0.9721819999999983)

(benchmark-run 100000
  (replace-string-in-string "." "bar" "foo.buzz"))

  => (11.877136 86 3.1208540000000013)
```

haxe-replace-string is looking good

Comment: The time for `haxe-replace-string` is probably so bad because you didn't byte-compile it? `loop` macro really makes compiling a must, it's very slow otherwise.

Comment: updated with some more numbers

Comment: (replace-regexp-in-string "\\." "bar" "foo.buzz") => "foobarbuzz"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun replace-in-string (what with in)
  (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote what) with in nil 'literal))
```

Comment: The second to last paren should be moved outside, but otherwise yes this works. There's no builtin for this? Seems like such a weird thing to be left out.

Comment: @spike I read somewhere that the suggested way is to create a temporary buffer, copy the string there and to `replace-string` on the buffer. It would be interesting if that way it be any faster.

Comment: This fails to replace slashes: `(replace-in-string "\\" "\\\\" "\\")` returns `"\\")` instead of `"\\\\")`.

Comment: `replace-regexp-in-string` doesn't work in non-interactive mode if the `with` contains escape sequences. That is due to the way the string is processed. In that case you're forced to use `re-search-string` and `replace-match` instead. See this answer for more details: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/31869/13140

Answer (score 26):

[`s.el`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) string manipulation library has [`s-replace`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-replace-old-new-s) function:

```
(s-replace "." "bar" "foo.buzz") ;; => "foobarbuzz"
```

I recommend installing `s.el` from Emacs package manager, if you work with strings in your Elisp.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. More so, since the OP seems to be asking exactly for this.

Comment: The OP was asking for a single function, not an entire library of string functionality.  Also, it means installing something extra (which will be less desirable for some).  It's a good answer, but I see no reason why it *should* be the accepted answer -- the others are every bit as suitable.

Answer (score 12):

Emacs 28.1 (still in development at time of writing) provides this as standard:

```
** New function 'string-replace'.
This function works along the line of 'replace-regexp-in-string', but
matching on strings instead of regexps, and does not change the global
match state.
```

```
(string-replace FROMSTRING TOSTRING INSTRING)

Replace FROMSTRING with TOSTRING in INSTRING each time it occurs.

(string-replace ".*" "BAR" "foo.*bar.*baz")
 ⇒ "fooBARbarBARbaz"
```

Comment: Works now since 28 is released. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'd not hope for this to be faster:

```
(defun haxe-replace-string (string string-a string-b)
  "Because there's no function in eLisp to do this."
  (loop for i from 0 upto
        (- (length string) (length string-a))
        for c = (aref string i)
        with alen = (length string-a)
        with result = nil
        with last = 0
        do (loop for j from i below (+ i alen)
                 do (unless
                        (char-equal
                         (aref string-a (- j i))
                         (aref string j))
                      (return))
                 finally
                 (setq result
                       (cons (substring string last (- j alen)) result)
                       i (1- j) last j))
        finally
        (return
         (if result 
             (mapconcat
              #'identity
              (reverse (cons (substring string last) result)) string-b)
           string))))
```

Becasue `replace-regexp-in-string` is a native function, but you never know... Anyways, I wrote this some time ago for some reason, so, if you fill like comparing the performance - you are welcome to try :)

Another idea, using temporary buffer:

```
(defun replace-string-in-string (what with in)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert in)
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (while (search-forward what nil t)
      (replace-match with nil t))
    (buffer-string)))
```

Answer (score 5):

`s-replace` is fine if you are ready to require it, but say you want to use a replace in string feature early in the load process and don't yet have `s.el` loaded or don't need all of it. Well, here is the definition of `s-replace` from `s.el`. As you can see, it has no dependencies so you can use it without requiring the rest of `s.el`:

```
(defun s-replace (old new s)
  "Replaces OLD with NEW in S."
  (declare (pure t) (side-effect-free t))
  (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote old) new s t t))
```